# Saving *.so libraries from .jar library in android apk

Tags: java, android

I have an android gradle project with a custom jar library, which contains some structure with *.so files (android-x86 build):

```
...
|--org
   \--example
      \--test_app
         \--android_x86
            |--macro
            |  |--macro.conf
            |  \--libmacro.so
            |--engine
            |  |--engine.so
            |  \--engine.conf
            |--config.xml
            \--version.xml
...
```

I had successfully added it to android project with gradle, but resulting apk file contains following structure without *.so files:

```
...
|--org
   \--example
      \--test_app
         \--android_x86
            |--macro
            |  \--macro.conf
            |--engine
            |  \--engine.conf
            |--config.xml
            \--version.xml
...
```

Here is build.gradle config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vs.kstat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.5.0@aar'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I know there’s jniLibs directory to place *.so libraries, but I need to keep current structure with *.so files. How do I configure gradle project so that the build doesn't delete *.so files?